# JMeter can`t Log in using cookies

Tags: cookies, authentication, jmeter

Test Plan:

```
HTTP Cookie manager
1. Open Login Page (get) - (send cookie with with JSESSIONID)
2. Log in (post) - (send cookie with with LtpaToken2, receive cookie with JSESSIONID)
3. Create new app (post)
```

Path contains ;jsessionid=${jsessionid} in Log in (post)

I have strange behavior. I get login page in response in post methods, thus request sent without exceptions but didn`t log in.
Also I noticed there are different JSESSIONID for every operation.

For example

```
step1: Request - no cookies, Sampler result - Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=00005VALCRoQLgAgEsC_CIOVc5x:-1; Path=/
step2: Request - Cookie Data:JSESSIONID=00005VALCRoQLgAgEsC_CIOVc5x:-1,  Sampler result - Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000OnEiWZdVvxMa8n0Sew2_4Pl:-1; Path=/
Step3: Request - Cookie Data:JSESSIONID=0000OnEiWZdVvxMa8n0Sew2_4Pl:-1 , Sampler result - Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000xbnlZFrZuYSdaY12--sdgg1:-1; Path=/
```

What is wrong with my script? I need to log in portal.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not actual anymore. HTTP Cookie Manager manage all session cookies by default (Jsession and ldap). I set following parameters:

- Clear cookie each iteration =Yes
- Cookie Policy = Compatible
- Implementation = HC4CookieHandler